# : MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, deployment, connection

I'm encountering an error while running my Node.js application with MongoDB. Here are the details:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtsiV.png)

I have a Kubernetes deployment running my Node.js application. The application connects to a MongoDB instance. I'm using Mongoose as the ODM. The error occurs when trying to establish a connection to the MongoDB instance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpDsO.png)

Checked the connection string and ensured it is correct.

Verified the network configuration of my Kubernetes cluster.

Checked the DNS resolution for the hostname "mongo".
Verified the permissions of the MongoDB user.
Reviewed the MongoDB configuration